# URL was not found on this server laravel

Tags: laravel-5

project is working fine on localhost but when I upload it on server it shows

```
Not Found
```

The requested URL /yes was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

only / route is working other route is not working on route.php file

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to setup `.htaccess` rewrite on your server. You may need to install and enable the `mod_rewrite` apache module (or similar alternative for your chosen http server).

Check that the public folder for your app has a `.htaccess` file, similar to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

[See latest laravel release](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.27/public/.htaccess).

Answer (score 3):

.dotfiles are hidden makesure you enable show hidden files on your control panel.

in Laravel 5.6^ edit the `.htacess` file copied from public and paste this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also do same at public/.htacess or public_html/.htacess

Comment: thanks man, you saved my life! I created this file inside /public and it's works for me.

Answer (score 2):

pp has a .htaccess file, similar to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `RewriteBase` with your folder in `project_folder/.htaccess` and `project_folder/public/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /your_project_folder/public

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: its worked for me .... my server url for second line is /home2/mydomain name and its worked like charm. thank you. god bless you forever.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I copied the .htaccess file in my public folder in the localhost and pasted it to the .htaccess file on the server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation. When .htaccess isn't present on the public_html folder and the php version is been changed or upgraded there is  that is been generated inside the .htaccess file. So please check properly to see if it's there before the  of laravel .htaccess. It seems the mime_module specifies the version for the project